# Dropping "#" links from Scrapy crawl

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I'm [running this spider](https://gist.github.com/chrisfromthelc/813a19adfa26d3e992cc06ac8c4913ae) on a site. It works fine, but one problem I'm running into is that there are a number of hrefs with "#" as the link.

How can I skip or drop those # links altogether? I'm outputting the links to a file currently, and using the `lstrip` dumps "" to the file. I've also tried `i.replace`, but it still drops a blank line in the file.

Comment: Can you clarify your intention? would you like to remove the '#' from the string? of ignore it all?

Comment: It's generally a good idea to post the relevant portions of code *here*, rather than host them at some 3rd party link.

Answer (score 1):

For everything that matches your selector, you're `yield`ing. Conditionally `yield`, so convert:

```
for i in selector.extract():
    yield {"url": i.lstrip('#')}
```

into something like

```
for i in selector.extract():
    url = i.lstrip('#')
    if url:
        yield {"url": url}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to skip those links, you need to change XPath expression to extract href attribute only if they don't contain "#"

```
selector = response.xpath('//*/a[not(contains(@href, "#"))]/@href')
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! I had actually tried `not(contains())` previously, but it seems my syntax was wrong. Thanks!